# ChartJS Add dynamic labels to vertical lines on horizontal bar chart

Tags: javascript, graph, chart.js, bar-chart

I am trying to get a horizontal bar chart with 3 overlay vertical lines at specific points on the horizontal axis. I am using ChartJS v2.8 and the annotations plugin (v 0.5.5). I would like to add a binding label to each of the 3 vertical lines (created with annonations), as shown in this image. Here is the script I am using.

```
  <canvas id="myChart" height="600" ></canvas>
```

JS script:

````
let     per10 = 3.718,
        per50 = 5,
        per90 = 6.282;


let scales =    ["SEMESTER 1","Course 1","Course 2","Course 3","Course 4",,"SEMESTER 2","Course 1","Course 2","Course 3","Course 4",,"SEMESTER 1","Course 1","Course 2","Course 3","Course 4",,"SEMESTER 1","Course 1","Course 2","Course 3","Course 4",,"SEMESTER 1","Course 1","Course 2","Course 3","Course 4",,"SEMESTER 1","Course 1","Course 2","Course 3","Course 4",,"Course 5"  ]
    
    
let scores =  [3.6, 6.1, 7.4, 4.7, 5.6, ,  5.9, 4.1, 3.9, 6.4, 5.9, ,  5.9, 4.1, 3.9, 6.4, 5.9, ,  5.9, 4.1, 3.9, 6.4, 5.9, ,  5.9, 4.1, 3.9, 6.4, 5.9, ,  5.9, 4.1, 3.9, 6.4, 5.9, ,7.5];

    
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

  Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
  Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.enabled = false;


var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',

  data: {
    labels: scales,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Score',
        display: false,
        showTooltip: false,
        data: scores,
        backgroundColor: 'royalBlue',
        borderColor: '#000000',
        borderWidth: 0,
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    showTooltips: false,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: false,
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          fixedStepSize: 1
        },
        gridLines: {display: false}
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 8,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: false,
        },
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: false,
          stepSize: 2,
          beginAtZero: true,

        },
        position: 'bottom',
        gridLines: {display: false}
        
      }]
    },

    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Scores'
    },
        
    events: [],
    autocolors: false,
      
    annotation: {
      annotations: [
      {
        type: 'line',
        mode: 'vertical',
        scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
        value: per10,
        borderColor: '#db7093',
        borderWidth: 2, 
        label: {
            display: true,
          value: "10%"
        }
      },
      {
        type: 'line',
        mode: 'vertical',
        scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
        value: per50,
        borderColor: '#98fb98',
        borderWidth: 2, 
        label: {
            display: true,
          value: "50%"
        }
      },
      {
        type: 'line',
        mode: 'vertical',
        scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
        value: per90,
        borderColor: '#add8e6',
        borderWidth: 2, 
        label: {
            display: true,
          value: "90%"
        }
      },
      
      ]
    },
    
    animation: {
      duration: 0,
      onComplete: function() {
        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseLine = 'bottom';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
          console.log(dataset);
          for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
            for (var key in dataset._meta) {
              var model = dataset._meta[key].data[i]._model;
              model.y = model.y + 4;
              model.x = model.x -12;

              if (dataset.data[i] < 0.75) {
                model.x = model.x + 5;
              };

              ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x, model.y);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
});```
````

Another question: How can I reduce the space between blocks of bars? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of generated bar chart]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TSAcc/5fuw3rL6/26/)

Comment: Maybe you can use the annotation plugin: https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/

Comment: I have seen only now you are already using the plugin. :(

Comment: Any ideas on how to reduce the space between the cateogries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using an old version of chartjs-plugin-annotation, you need to consult  the related documentation for Line Annotations [here](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/tree/v0.5.5#line-annotations).

This will lead you to the following solution

```
annotation: {
  annotations: [
  {
    type: 'line',
    mode: 'vertical',
    scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
    value: per10,
    borderColor: '#db7093',
    borderWidth: 2, 
    label: {
      enabled: true,
      xAdjust: -22,
      content: '10%',
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      fontSize: 14,          
      fontColor: '#db7093',
      position: 'top'
    }
  },
  ...
```

Please take a look at your amended [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bgmx20sq/) and see how it works.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your solutions. Both answers pointed me in the same direction and the labels are displayed with your fix in place. I changed `xAdjust : -22`  to `xAdjust: 0` to get the label right on top of the line. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

To define the label in line annotation, for version 0.55, you must use `enabled` and `content`, and not `display` and `value`.

```
annotation: {
  annotations: [
  {
    type: 'line',
    mode: 'vertical',
    scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
    value: per10,
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 2, 
    label: {
      enabled: true, // <-- not display
      content: "10%", // <-- not value
      position: "top"
    }
  },
  {
    type: 'line',
    mode: 'vertical',
    scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
    value: per50,
    borderColor: '#98fb98',
    borderWidth: 2, 
    label: {
      enabled: true, // <-- not display
      content: "50%", // <-- not value
      position: "top"
    }
  },
  {
    type: 'line',
    mode: 'vertical',
    scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
    value: per90,
    borderColor: '#add8e6',
    borderWidth: 2, 
    label: {
      enabled: true, // <-- not display
      content: "90%", // <-- not value
      position: "top"
    }
  },
  ]
},
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I added the background and xAdjust properties and the chart is working as expected now. Thank you for taking time to help me out.